# Is there a way to use picker/selectInput in conjunction with an editable, reactive DT in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have struggled with the following issue and have found no suitable solution on SO.

Here is what I require from my DataTable

1. I would like to edit my DataTable (achieved)
2. Filter the data in DataTable with my edits intact. Currently, my edits disappear after I change the filters
3. Save whole DataTable as RDS rather than just the current displayed data based on filters. Currently, I just save the current displayed DataTable based on filters

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
df <- iris

species <- unique(as.character(df$Species))
width <- unique(df$Petal.Width)
#==========================================UI=======================================================#
ui = navbarPage("CSAT & SA", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis",
                         sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                             pickerInput(inputId = "species",
                                         label = "Species", selected = species,
                                         choices = species, multiple = T, 
                                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                                        `select-all-text` = "Select All", `none-selected-text` = "None Selected")),
                             pickerInput(inputId = "width",
                                         label = "Petal Width", selected = width,
                                         choices = width, multiple = T, 
                                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                                        `select-all-text` = "Select All", `none-selected-text` = "None Selected")),
                             width = 2, 
                             actionButton(inputId = "save", label = "Save"), 
                             actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update")
                           ),
                           mainPanel(
                             h2("Iris"), fluidRow(
                               tabPanel("Iris", DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
                                        width = 12)
                             )))))
#==========================================SERVER=======================================================#

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  SA <- reactive({
    df<-df %>%
      filter(Species %in% input$species) %>%
      filter(Petal.Width %in% input$width)
  }) 
  
  
  rec_val = reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  
  observe({
    rec_val$SA <- SA()
  })
  
  output$x1 = renderDT(SA(),  selection = 'none', editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns=c(0,1,2))))
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
  
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    info = input$x1_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col   
    v = info$value
    rec_val$SA[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rec_val$SA[i, j])
    replaceData(proxy, rec_val$SA, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    saveRDS(rec_val$SA, "somewhere.rds") # write new data out
    
  })

  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:**

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMhYS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `updatePickerInput()` to update the choices available based on the edits.  Also, define row id to keep the modified data. Using reset you can return to the original datatable.  Try this

```
library(shinythemes)
dat <- iris

species <- unique(as.character(dat$Species))
width <- unique(dat$Petal.Width)
#==========================================UI=======================================================#
ui = navbarPage("CSAT & SA", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis",
                         sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                             pickerInput(inputId = "species",
                                         label = "Species", selected = species,
                                         choices = as.list(species), multiple = T, 
                                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                                        `select-all-text` = "Select All", `none-selected-text` = "None Selected")),
                             pickerInput(inputId = "width",
                                         label = "Petal Width", selected = width,
                                         choices = as.list(width), multiple = T, 
                                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                                        `select-all-text` = "Select All", `none-selected-text` = "None Selected")),
                             width = 2, 
                             actionButton(inputId = "save", label = "Save"), 
                             actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset")
                           ),
                           mainPanel(
                             h2("Iris"), fluidRow(
                               tabPanel("Iris", DT::dataTableOutput("x1"), DTOutput("x2"),
                                        width = 12)
                             )))))
#==========================================SERVER=======================================================#

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  SA <- reactive({
    row_id <- c(1:nrow(dat))
    data <- data.frame(dat,row_id)
    data
  })
  
  rv = reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  observe({
    rv$df <- SA() %>%
      filter(Species %in% isolate(input$species)) %>%
      filter(Petal.Width %in% isolate(input$width))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$species, {
                  df1 <- SA()         ### orig data
                  df2 <- rv$df        ### modified data
                  if (is.null(df2)){
                    rvdf <- SA()
                  }else{
                    vn <- colnames(df1)
                    vnx <- paste0(vn,".x")
                    vny <- paste0(vn,".y")

                    rvdf <- left_join(df1, df2, by="row_id") %>% transmute(var1 = get(!!vnx[1]), var2 = get(!!vnx[2]), var3 = get(!!vnx[3]),
                                                                            var4 = ifelse(is.na(get(!!vny[4])), get(!!vnx[4]), get(!!vny[4])),
                                                                            var5 = get(!!vnx[5]),  # ifelse(is.na(get(!!vny[5])), get(!!vnx[5]), get(!!vny[5])),
                                                                            row_id)

                    colnames(rvdf) <- vn
                  }
                  rv$df <- rvdf  %>%
                    filter(Species %in% input$species) %>% 
                    filter(Petal.Width %in% input$width)

  })
  
  observeEvent(input$width, {
    df1 <- SA()         ### orig data
    df2 <- rv$df        ### modified data
    if (is.null(df2)){
      rvdf <- SA()
    }else{
      
      vn <- colnames(df1)
      vnx <- paste0(vn,".x")
      vny <- paste0(vn,".y")
      ###    keep modified data, if present; if not, keep original data
      rvdf <- left_join(df1, df2, by="row_id") %>% transmute(var1 = get(!!vnx[1]), var2 = get(!!vnx[2]), var3 = get(!!vnx[3]),
                                                              var4 = ifelse(is.na(get(!!vny[4])), get(!!vnx[4]), get(!!vny[4])),  ##  keep modified data
                                                              var5 = get(!!vnx[5]),  # ifelse(is.na(get(!!vny[5])), get(!!vnx[5]), get(!!vny[5])),
                                                              row_id)
      
      colnames(rvdf) <- vn
      
    }
    rv$df <- rvdf  %>%
      filter(Species %in% input$species) %>% 
      filter(Petal.Width %in% input$width)
    
  })
  
  output$x1 <- renderDT(rv$df,  selection = 'none',
                       editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns=c(0,1,2))),
                       options = list(
                         columnDefs = list(
                           list(
                             visible = FALSE,
                             targets = 6
                           )
                         )
                       )
                       )
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('x1')
  
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    info = input$x1_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col   
    v = info$value
    
    rv$df[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rv$df[i, j])
    
    #replaceData(proxy, rv$df, resetPaging = FALSE)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    #choicess <- as.list(unique(c(as.character(rv$df[,5]), as.character(SA()[,5]))))
    choicesp <- as.list(unique(c(rv$df[,4], SA()[,4])))
    # updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "species", choices = choicess, selected=choicess)
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "width", choices = choicesp, selected=choicesp)
    saveRDS(rv$df, "somewhere.rds") # write new data out
    
    df3 <- readRDS("C:/My Disk Space/_My Work/RStuff/GWS/somewhere.rds")
    output$x2 <- renderDT({
      df3
    })
    
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$df <- SA()
    # choicess <- unique(as.character(rv$df[,5]))
    choicesp <- unique(SA()[,4])
    # updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "species", choices = choicess, selected=choicess)
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "width", choices = choicesp, selected=choicesp)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello @YBS, everything works great. However, the filter function doesn't seem to work properly after saving changes. If I filter to make the edit, I am no longer able to return to no filters applied with my changes intact. Thanks again!

Comment: You may have to adjust the program to your use case.  I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Also, please note that as Species is character with 3 factor levels, you cannot edit those values; if you do, it will show blank (na).

Comment: Users may want to make many changes using different combinations of filters. Currently, this is not possible. User can only apply one filter, make edits based on one filter, save edits and then to make additional changes using different filters, one must reload the data. See my edit with screenshot. The first DT with change to petal width only shows values for Setosa, despite the filter for Setosa AND Virginica.

Comment: @ttam10, please see the updated code.  You may need to tweak it a bit to meet your needs.  You do need to click on save button to save the changes, and that will show updated choices for filters.  Please note that I have only implemented this for petal.width column.  You need to update, if necessary, to implement the same for other columns (in transmute...).  The table at the bottom is to show what was saved.  You can delete it.

Comment: Works seamlessly. TY!